# I want to get difference between current time and a time h:i:s AM in minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get time difference between current time(h:i:s AM/PM) and saved time(h:i:s AM/PM) in minutes.

Example: 01:00:00 PM(current Time) - 11:00:00 AM(saved time) = 120 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing your time as a legitimate `time` datatype, you can use `timediff()` to compute the difference with the current time, and then extract the hour portion:

```
hour(timediff(current_time, mytime))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check `date_diff` manual on [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php).

```
$origin = date_create('2020-10-11 13:00:00');
$target = date_create('2020-10-11 11:00:00');
$interval = date_diff($origin, $target);
print_r($interval);
echo $interval->format('%h hours %i minutes');
```

if you want diff in minutes :

```
$hours   = $interval->format('%h'); 
$minutes = $interval->format('%i');
echo  'Diff. in minutes is: '.($hours * 60 + $minutes);
```